# Fragment enters the back stack twice implicitly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have several Fragment that are outlined like this :

`MainActivity` that contains a `MainFragment` and a `WebFragment` (just a fragment that has a webview inside of it) :

```
 <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
            android:name="com.citylifeapps.cups.MainFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/venue_fragment"
            android:name="com.citylifeapps.cups.WebFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </fragment>

 </FrameLayout>
```

`MainFragment` that contains a `ListFragment` and a `MapFragment` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.citylifeapps.cups.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@id/list_fragment"
        android:name="com.citylifeapps.cups.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is the following scenario :

1. Start the app, `MainFragment` starts with the Map and List in the same screen
2. click on a list item, `WebFragment` opens up
3. Click back, `MainFragment` appears - as expected
4. Click another back - `WebFragment` is shown again

The last step (4) is the problem. The expected behaviour is that from the `MainFragment` (step 3), clicking back will close the app as it is the highest in the chain.

I assume I am doing something wrong with the back stack,

I am trying to debug it but it is extremely hard to debug.

Here is the FragmentManager log :

```
// Step 1

09-16 16:00:15.683: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #0: HIDE WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:15.683: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #1: SHOW MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: MapFragment{41e68c60 #1 id=0x7f05002a}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: SupportMapFragment{41e6adc8 #2 id=0x7f050084}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: ListFragment{42058380 #3 id=0x7f05002b}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): hide: WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): show: MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto STARTED: MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto STARTED: MapFragment{41e68c60 #1 id=0x7f05002a}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto STARTED: SupportMapFragment{41e6adc8 #2 id=0x7f050084}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto STARTED: ListFragment{42058380 #3 id=0x7f05002b}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto STARTED: WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto RESUMED: MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto RESUMED: MapFragment{41e68c60 #1 id=0x7f05002a}
09-16 16:00:15.733: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto RESUMED: SupportMapFragment{41e6adc8 #2 id=0x7f050084}
09-16 16:00:15.743: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto RESUMED: ListFragment{42058380 #3 id=0x7f05002b}
09-16 16:00:15.743: V/FragmentManager(22278): moveto RESUMED: WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}

// Step 2

09-16 16:00:28.967: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #0: SHOW MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:28.967: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #1: HIDE WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:28.977: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #0: HIDE MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:28.977: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #1: SHOW WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:28.977: V/FragmentManager(22278): Bump nesting of MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081} to 1
09-16 16:00:28.977: V/FragmentManager(22278): Bump nesting of WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082} to 1
09-16 16:00:28.977: V/FragmentManager(22278): show: MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:28.977: V/FragmentManager(22278): hide: WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:28.977: V/FragmentManager(22278): Bump nesting of MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081} to 2
09-16 16:00:28.977: V/FragmentManager(22278): Bump nesting of WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082} to 2
09-16 16:00:28.977: V/FragmentManager(22278): hide: MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:28.997: V/FragmentManager(22278): show: WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}

// Step 3

09-16 16:00:39.238: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #0: HIDE MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:39.238: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #1: SHOW WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:39.238: V/FragmentManager(22278): Bump nesting of MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081} to 1
09-16 16:00:39.238: V/FragmentManager(22278): Bump nesting of WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082} to 1
09-16 16:00:39.238: V/FragmentManager(22278): hide: WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:39.238: V/FragmentManager(22278): show: MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}

// Step 4

09-16 16:00:53.724: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #0: SHOW MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
09-16 16:00:53.724: D/FragmentManager(22278):     Op #1: HIDE WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:53.724: V/FragmentManager(22278): Bump nesting of MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081} to 0
09-16 16:00:53.724: V/FragmentManager(22278): Bump nesting of WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082} to 0
09-16 16:00:53.724: V/FragmentManager(22278): show: WebFragment{42037ea8 #4 id=0x7f050082}
09-16 16:00:53.724: V/FragmentManager(22278): hide: MainFragment{41e678a0 #0 id=0x7f050081}
```

I don't understand what's wrong, The only time I add the WebFragment to the back stack is when I click the list item and open it up in step 2. Also I assume that calling `super.onBackPressed()` pops the back stack as well.

Here is the simplified version of my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private boolean venueOrMapPageVisible = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .hide(getVenueFragment())
        .show(getMainFragment())
        .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        if (venueOrMapPageVisible) {
            setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            venueOrMapPageVisible = false;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (venueOrMapPageVisible) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
            break;


        return false;
    }



    // called when a venue is clicked
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(JSONObject venue) {

        if (venue != null) {
            String vid = null;
            try {
                vid = venue.getString("key");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            openVenue(vid);
        }
    }


    private void openVenue(String vid) {
        getVenueFragment().loadUrl(Consts.venueUri(vid));

        MainActivity.this
                .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                .hide(getMainFragment())
                .show(getVenueFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        venueOrMapPageVisible = true;

        // analytics open venue start time (set it only once)
        if (CupsTracker.venueStartTime == 0L) {
            CupsTracker.venueStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }


    private WebFragment getVenueFragment() {
        return (WebFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.venue_fragment);
    }

    private MainFragment getMainFragment() {
        return (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
    }




    public void moveToMapFragment() {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
        .hide(listFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
        mapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        venueOrMapPageVisible = true;

    }

}
```

I suspect that since the MainActivity layout file contains both the `MainFragment` and `WebFragment`, when it is inflated, WebFragment somehow implicitly added to the back stack or something. Is it possible ?

Comment: Can you put your java code? You can use just one fragment inside your activity, and manage them inside java using FragmentManager(replace method), there you have full control about back stack.

Comment: I didn't want to put the code as it is a little complicated, I'll try to simplify it and update the question. But can you elaborate a little about what you wrote ? What implicit ops to the back stack does the framework do in my case ? Also, how does the Activity know to show the `MainFragment` and hide the `WebFragment` on default even when I didn't specify it in the code ? Does it know just by the order it is defined in the XML ?

Comment: Ok, what I suggested is a bit "harder" to implement, you need more lines of code. However, you will have full control, because you must tell what you should or shouldn't  put on back stack. I will prepare a code using this.

Before you try that, how do add the framgment in back stack? How do you hide and show your fragments? Can you put just that piece of code?

Comment: @BrunoMateus I've added the code. I'm not sure what happens when the layout inflates. does it automatically add both the Fragments to the backstack ?

Comment: I am thinking about that. When you create your view, at some time both fragment will be added ok? But they are added as a simple fragmentTransaction or two fragmentTransaction? I don't know.

When you click on back, o step 4, both fragments are visible ?

Try to debug using this method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#getBackStackEntryCount()

Your code seems  correct!